# Are both "see you at the lesson" and "see you in the lesson" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have been studying English with many teachers. Some of them say "See you in the lesson" while others say "See you at the lesson." Yesterday, one of them told me that the correct way of saying it is "See you at the lesson."

Are both of them correct? If one (or both) of them is incorrect, please tell me why.

Comment: Please leave a comment, tell me why you voted down this question? :)

Answer (score 2):

**In American usage,** both of these phrases are correct grammar, but they don't mean the same thing, and *at* is probably the intended meaning. *At* merely implies you and the teacher will be in the same place. *In* would be acceptable if your lesson were a performance, which in a classroom setting it *might* be. You might find this easier if we contrast "see you at the movie" with "see you in the movie".

Having said that, prepositions can behave rather arbitrarily and **non-American** usage may differ.

Comment: I want to back up Andrew completely here. In American usage, a lesson is not considered a place, but rather an event. It has no "in" and so only the first one is correct. However, I also have the sense that both would be acceptable in Britain.

Comment: Also @leoger Incidentally, the question is not about *lesson*, but the preposition use. Try substituting *lesson* with *class*, *school*, or whatever you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Note that the question is not related to "American usage" at all, but the English language.

Comment: @Kris, my knowledge of non-American usage is sometimes not enough to answer an ELU question. Most of the time, I'm aware that my knowledge holds for the English language wherever it is spoken, but in this case, I'm not at all sure. It's not like algebra, where anyone can supply a universal answer. **In terms of the English language,** both versions are semantically correct. Whether they mean what the speaker intends can not be determined from the parts of speech, but by knowing how the phrase in understood by the people who are speaking.

Comment: @Kris, If someone asked "What is the difference between'I am going to knock you up?' and 'I am going to knock you out'", would you say that American vs non-American usage doesn't matter and it's a question of preposition use? The latter phrase has a _completely_ different meaning depending where you are.

Comment: @Kris, I read this question as pertaining to the *combination* of "in/at" and "lesson". Where did you read anything that indicates otherwise? I understand you're trying to be helpful but I'm not sure you're entirely right on this one.